# 'ORA-46632: password-based keystore does not exist' but the file ewallet.p12 exists

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, keystore, oracle-wallet

I'm using Oracle 12c and when I try to create an auto-login keystore with this command :

```
ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT
CREATE AUTO_LOGIN KEYSTORE FROM KEYSTORE 
'home/BetaCrasher/app/BetaCrasher/admin/orcl/wallet'
IDENTIFIED BY hello;
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-46632: password-based keystore does not exist
```

I check the path and the file for the keystore is there.
I also tried using this path and it still doesn't work

```
'home/BetaCrasher/app/BetaCrasher/admin/orcl/wallet/ewallet.p12'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing a leading slash in your path, since it appears to be a full path to the wallet folder.

Also, don't forget to grant access to the path to your Oracle's OS user.